# View Scroll UI Issue

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have an issue with my UI being able to scroll perfectly without changing the size of my white view. I tried changing the content compression and giving it an intrinsic size to no avail. Here is my UI before being scrolled and after. Help me fix my scrolling issue.

My UI before being scrolled

[image]

My UI after being scrolled

[image]

Comment: You need to provide much more information on your layout. The two images you've shown do not even look like content in a scroll view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I had to clip the white view to bounds.